# Setting a text value on map click in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

> Blockquote

I am trying this code to change the "tap_text" value to the click coordinates. I copied the whole code from githuub mapdemo.
The maps loads but then the "tap_text" never changes on click. Even when I try this manually nothing happens. I dont get any error message.

```
mTapTextView.setText("loaded");
```

The whole code:

```
package com.dji.amirdji;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This shows how to listen to some {@link GoogleMap} events.
 */
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    private TextView mTapTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mTapTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap_text);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + point);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("long pressed, point=" + point);
    }

}
```

I call this in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".common.MapsActivity"
    android:label="Map" />
```

Comment: i think the issue is the java file is not read at all. although it is in my android manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the class instead of the view and it solved the problem.

```
mBtnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
  mBtnMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

            // Getting the position from the marker
            clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            title.setText(args.getTitle());

            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                {
                    if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                    {   
                        if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                            tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                            for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                            {
                                String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                {  
                                    task = tmptask;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
            return v;

        }
    });
```